# os.environ.get("key") returns none; hardcoding "key" works

Tags: python, flask

Building a python 3 web app using flask which includes google maps.

Checking for API Key before loading index.html always raises RuntimeError:

```
if not os.environ.get("key"):
    raise RuntimeError("key not set")
return render_template("index.html", key=os.environ.get("key"))
```

Also tried `os.getenv` - the same problem occurs. Changing variable name does not solve the issue either.

Exported the variable to environment via `export key=value` and `printenv` returns correct value of `key`.

Hardcoding the API Key works and returns the map successfully:

```
return render_template("index.html", key=value)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: How do you start the server? Do you export the variable and then execute `flask run`? Or some other way?

Comment: Check the process environment via `tr '\0' '\n' </proc/PID/environ` with the PID of your server. If `key` isn't in there, it's (provably!) not a Python problem.

Comment: yes, export the variable and then ``flask run```. Also tried exporting after, no change.

Comment: ...and *show your work*. Right now, nothing in the question but an unsupported assertion leads us to think that the value is actually correctly exported in the environment (and often, the reason someone *has* a question or problem is that the things they believe to be true are not -- making any assertion innately a point on which verification/validation/debugging is appropriate).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the suggestion. ran the `tr` command and flask did not indeed have the `key`. the instructions I followed were given by cs50 curriculum and worked previously for another app. Not sure what is the issue still.

However, I have solved it by creating `websiteconfig.py` file with `key=value`. found it here: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/2/
This seems like a better solution as well.

Not sure how I can show more of my work in addition to what I wrote above. However, I see your point. Can you give any suggestions for future questions on what I should include?

Comment: Showing the exact shell commands used to export the variable and start the app (in the context of how they're invoked in practice) would be a place to start.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you very much for the suggestions - solved it. issue was running the `export var` in a different terminal window than `flask run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: make sure to run the `export var` command in the same terminal window as `flask run`.

ALTERNATIVE: create `websiteconfig.py` file with `key="value"` and include `import websiteconfig` in your application. source: [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/2)